# Redirect everything except images

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I cant understand why but:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} market\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^market\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(png|jpe?g|bmp|gif|swf|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://market.mysite.com/$1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Works as expected. Redirecting images to an other domain. But this one:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} market\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^market\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(png|jpe?g|bmp|gif|swf|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://market.mysite.com/$1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Will redirect all no matter what. What I want to see is to redirect all except images.
What I am trying to do in my rules above is to redirect all sub-domains of market.mysite.com to market.mysite.com if it wasn't market.mysite.com and if it wasn't an image. In another word:

```
cdn.market.mysite.com -> market.mysite.com

cdn.market.mysite.com/blahblah.html -> market.mysite.com/blahblah.html

cdn.market.mysite.com/blahblah.png -> NO REDIRECT

market.mysite.com -> NO REDIRECT
```

I use wildcard sub-domain so all of my market sub-sub-domains will use same directory. And then responding to all of requests by one php file. index.php

Thanks,

Comment: The `!` exclusion condition works fine for me if I add that 4 line rule into a blank htaccess file. Anything endind with one of those extensions don't get redirected

Comment: Has you problem been solved?

Comment: Not yet. I still can t get it working.

Comment: Sample site is: store.irgservers.com/test.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your existing code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.market\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+.+?\.(png|jpe?g|bmp|gif|swf|css|js)[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://market.mysite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Test in a different browser or clear your existing browser cache.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But it still redirect images as well as other pages.

Comment: It didn't redirect images as per my tests. Do you have other stuff in your .htaccess also? Are there other .htaccess files in your DOCUMENT_ROOT? Finally is there nay framework in place here controlling this behavior?

Comment: The only change I did to your code was removing "Options" line. Because it will makes error #500. I am using Apache 2.2.3. Also no other htaccess and no framework. Do you want me to give you site address?

Comment: Yes please provide me your site address. I am sure it is something easy to fix. Also Options line shouldn't cause 500 error, I suspect some mis configuration somewhere. Can you tail your error.log for the cause of 500 error.

Comment: 500 error is because of using "FollowSymLinks". Nothing important AFAIK. My server is currently under DNS DDos Attack. I will give you a sample address ASAP. Thank you for replying.

Comment: store.irgservers.com/test.png

Comment: Thanks for providing that URL, I will investigate in few hours once I reach back to my computer.

Comment: I checked `store.irgservers.com/test.png` and it seems it is going to index.php. I request you please upload your full & latest .htaccess in your question (or provide me paste bin URL) so that I can investigate and suggest.

Comment: Also can you tell me if you have any PHP or CMS framework (like WP, CI, Joomla etc) working here well?

Comment: as you can clearly see there is nothing except php file and htaccess file. And htaccess is as you said: http://i39.tinypic.com/344d0uv.png

Comment: Examined your `.htaccess` and it seems there is disconnect between your written requirement and my understanding. Is there any cdn URL here or not as stated in your question. You seem to be testing with: `http://store.irgservers.com/test.png` which is not actually a cdn URL. In anycase I have made another edit please check and let me know.

Comment: Actually I typed the address incorrect. Sorry. It must be http://cdn.store.irgservers.com/test.png

Comment: Does `test.png` actually exist on csn host?

Comment: Thank you a lot. Edit solved the problem. Yet I cant understand why! :D

Comment: You're most welcome, glad that it solved the problem. Trick was to use: `%{THE_REQUEST}` (this is original request as received by Apache which doesn't get overwritten by various rules).

Comment: I see. So I expect a new problem now. AFAIK %{THE_REQUEST} will return string query as well so we need to change rule a little.

Comment: Yes `%{THE_REQUEST}` will return everything including query string but the regex I am using: `\.(png|jpe?g|bmp|gif|swf|css|js)\s` will only match URL **without** query string (dot followed by image extensions followed by a space).

Comment: Is this possible to allow query string too? I am not very familiar with regex but is this possible to prevent redirecting of both blah.png and blan.png?t=12345678&... ?! Sometimes my images have time-stamp too because you know using cdn and caching.

Comment: I added an other bounty (+100rep) and I will give it as soon as stack-overflow let me do. I know that this is not even close to what your time is really worth. Sry,

Comment: You're most welcome, I am here to help fellow SO members as much as I can and to the best of my knowledge. Your's was really an interesting problem. I am glad that it worked out for you.